# Is it allowed prove the theorem with lemma first

Tags: proof-writing

Sorry for this silly question, because I'ven't studied proof theory. Maybe I have a little misconception about this.

Anyway, Suppose I have to prove a theorem. The theorem has the highest generalization, which is we just can't prove the theorem without prove something under the level. And presume that the second level needs the other proofs too.

I already know about lemma that is can be used for proving the theorem.

In other words, my question :

> Is it allowed to prove some big theorem which has a statement that we don't know about it with proving the simple statement first? Is this statement called by *Lemma*?

I found this situation when I read the Jordan's Curve Theorem. My brain can't understand this, but at least if it's true, then I'll learn something new.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Yes, that's a standard method of proof used all the time

Comment: We typically prove big theorems through a series of smaller lemmas to make the work easier or clearer in exposition, yes.

Comment: Is your question really related to [proof theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory)?

Comment: @HanulJeon a bit i think. I was talking about informal proof.

Comment: The distinction between theorem and lemma is artificial, so they are not  distinguished formally. In this reason, I think [proof-theory] tag is not adequate to your question. (This is the reason why I remove it.)